# Oracle SQL: Creating unique teamid from existing table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table dept(deptname, color). I would like to create a unique teamid by selecting the first 3 chars of the deptname and the first 2 chars of the color and a corresponding number. I got the SQL part down but don't know what the next step is

```
select deptname, upper(substr(1,3), color upper(substr(1,2)
from dept;
```

Here is my dept table

```
DEPTNAME............COLOR
SALES...............Orange
ACCOUNTING..........Blue
```

And my output should be

```
SALOR1
ACCBL2
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what your "corresponding number" requirement is - sequential? random? should it always be the same?

Comment: Sorry, I meant any arbitrary number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're using this for, you could just use rownum:

```
select upper(substr(deptname,1,3)) || upper(substr(color,1,2)) 
|| rownum from dept;
```

There is no guarantee that running this sql will always produce the same teamid each time it is run though.  For that, you'd have to add another column with a number in.